# Explicit thread safety keyword/macro for compile time checking

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++

I'm currently working on a medium-to-large C++ application which has a networked interface (similar to a multithreaded RPC service).

The networked interface communicates with a fairly complex application state. I think I've done a good job of keeping the non-thread-safe state (maps, vectors, etc) surrounded by mutexes, but I'm not sure.

I think it'd be really cool if I could specify which functions are thread safe and have it checked at compile time so that I don't have to run static analysers on my code. I'm fine with annotating all of my functions.

I'm currently stuck trying to come up with a way to fulfill the following examples with macros/template metaprogramming, but if this is natively possible, or a library to do this already exists, I'd rather use that.

```cpp
void not_thread_safe foo() {
    // some unsafe code
}

void called_from_multiple_threads bar() {
    foo(); // causes compile time error
}
```

```cpp
// note the thread_safe keyword/macro, vs the above not_thread_safe
void thread_safe foo() {
    std::lock_guard lock(some_mutex);
    // unsafe code
}

void called_from_multiple_threads bar() {
    foo(); // no error
}
```

```cpp
void not_thread_safe foo() {
    // unsafe code
}

void blah() {
    foo(); // bonus points if it catches this too (should be an error)
}

void called_from_multiple_threads bar() {
    blah();
}
```

Comment: There's nothing like this in C++ itself, and this is too broad/generic kind of a question. There are multiple approaches to guarantee, by contract, thread-safety; and in many cases the best approach is a matter of opinion. As such this would be off-topic for Stackoverflow. If you could, perhaps, narrow down the scope of your question to a single, specific, situation (or use case) then it might be possible to come up with an authoritative answer.

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html

Comment: The use case is primarily some sort of macro-like decorator/annotation for methods, which will cause a compile time error when conflicting macros are used. In the examples I gave, there's three macros - 'thread_safe', 'not_thread_safe', and 'called_from_multiple_threads'. The first two symbolise the method's thread safety. The final is a way of saying 'this method will be called from one or more unknown threads'. If a multithreaded method calls an unsafe method, there should be an error/warning printed. 1/2

Comment: The methods shouldn't have anything distinct about them in any other way (ie a suffix on the name, or a special return type). I could probably just add 'ThreadUnsafe' and 'ThreadSafe' to the corresponding methods, but I'd rather not. 2/2

Comment: At worst, you could always try stateful friend metaprogramming...